# Paginate a big text file

Tags: perl, unix

I have a big text file. Each line in the file is a record. And I need to parse the text file and show only 20 records in a HTML table at a time. I will have to support sorting as well.

What I am currently doing is read the file line by line based on the parameters start, stop, and page_size which is provided in querystring. It seems to work fine until I have to sort the records, because in order to sort I need to process every line in the text file.

So is there a Unix command which can I extract from line to line and sort? I tried grep but I do not know enough it to get this problem solved.

Comment: Put the data from the text file into a database.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [pr](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pr/) command. This is what we use to use all the time to paginate big files. You can set the page length, headers, footers, turn on line numbers, etc.

There's probably even a way to munge the output into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file?

```
man sort
```

[Here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort)